# Get ViewBag data from controllers to view

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I'm still learning MVC and I don't know if it's possible or not, but I want to display other views ViewBag data from controller to another view.

For Example:

[image]

How can I display `ViewBag.Message` to `Index.cshtml` View.

Comment: The message is an unlikely candidate for sharing.  What is your REAL scenario and why does it need to be passed from one view to another?

Comment: Learning and testing...

Comment: Two views shouldn't talk directly with one another.  What are you attempting to achieve; knowing that we can help you learn by pointing you in the right direction; what you're attempting suggests you're headed in the wrong direction currently.

Comment: If it is just the same text that you need to display in different views you could add it to your _Layout.cshtml view. No reason to assign it in the code to a ViewBag object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to use the same string to send to both views you can do this:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    const string SomeMessage = "Your application description page.";
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = SomeMessage;
        return View();
    }
    public ActionResult About()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = SomeMessage;
        return View();
    }
}
```

If you want to pass a string from the About page to the Index page you can do it by allowing the index page to accept a parameter, which you can pass in the querystring on a link to the index from the about page:

Home Controller

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index(string message)
    {
        ViewBag.Message = message;
        return View();
    }
    public ActionResult About()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Your application description page.";
        return View();
    }
}
```

About.cshtml

```
@Html.ActionLink("Link to index", "Index", new {message = ViewBag.Message})
```

Index.cshtml

```
@Html.DisplayFor(ViewBag.Message)
```

However the idea of sharing variables between views doesn't really make sense in the MVC concept.  When you go to a URL you invoke a controller.  This controller prepares some data (possibly pulling back data in the form of a model/models), which it passes to a view.  The view then renders this data onto a page which is returned to the user.

You may wish to look at this site to learn more about MVC and get a better idea of these concepts: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials

Comment: As @David L mentioned above passing data from one view to another is what I want? So your comment can be the answer instead of this.

Comment: No worries.  FYI: I've added to my answer in the hopes it goes some way towards showing you a way of doing what you're trying to achieve.  Good luck.